# Why onkeypress cannot detect Backspace keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

Why `onkeypress` cannot detect `Backspace keyboard` ?

first , fill `xxxxxxxxxx` into input type text and then press `submit button`
you will see red text `invalid email address` and press `backspace keyboard` for delete some char in input type text, Why `onkeypress` not work on backspace keyboard ?

http://jsfiddle.net/btetyLwb/1/

```
<script>
function clear_email_valid_text() {
        $('#valid_email').hide();
        $('#invalid_email').hide();
}


function validateForm() {
    var newsletters_email = document.forms["form_validate_email_newsletters"]["newsletters_email"].value;
    var atpos = newsletters_email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = newsletters_email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=newsletters_email.length) {
        $('#valid_email').hide();
        $('#invalid_email').show();
        return false;
    }
    else {         
        $('#valid_email').show();
        $('#invalid_email').hide();
        return false;   
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Because `onkeypress` fires only when a printable character is produced by the pressed key.

Comment: but i pressed key `backspace` why onkeypress not work ?

Comment: `backspace` is not a printable character. Use `onkeyup` instead, if you want to detect some specific keys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your text input not in focus, when you press BackSpace?

Try to add this:

```
document.forms["form_validate_email_newsletters"]["newsletters_email"].focus();
```

after $('#invalid_email').show();

Comment: If an input has not focus at the time `backspace` is pressed, the page will be redirected in most of the browsers.

Comment: @Teemu, yes. I suggested it, because in sample jsfiddle in my FF this handler (keypress) fired by pressing BackSpace.

Comment: Indeed, it works in FF, but not in IE or Chrome. Actually `onkeypress` is not a part of standard, and implementations vary through browsers. A "traditional" behavior of `onkeypress` have been the one I've described in my comment below the OP.